# DevExpress: Why does ChartControl.CustomDrawAxisLavel event occur multiple times?

Tags: devexpress

I've created simple application with the `DevExpress.XtraCharts.ChartControl`. To customize X-axis labels, I used `CustomDrawAxisLabel`.

But this event occurs twice during creation (once for all labels e.g. from 0 to 10 and one more time from 0 to 10) and 4 times when mouse moves.

How can i get it to occur only single time for all axis labels?

Comment: it's not possible. it fire for every series label..

Comment: True, it fires for every label, but multiple times...

Answer (score 0):

From: [CustomDrawAxisLabel Event is fired when moving the mouse over the Chart ?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q325077)

> According to our documentation the
>   [ChartControl.CustomDrawAxisLabel](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q325077) event is raised before drawing a
>   control. This means that if a control should be redrawn, this method
>   will be raised first. The parent form can force a control to be
>   redrawn even if it was not actually changed. In addition, you can
>   invalidate a control manually by calling the ChartControl method.
>   Please note that if you use any code that causes chart redrawing (
>   even indirectly ), this method will be raised, too.

Hope this satisfy your quest for finding for the reason.